# Формирование многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

никак не могу правильно перезаписать массив

первый массив заполняю так:

```
foreach ($_POST['case'] as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = DB::table('case_garage')->where('id_case', $key)->get();
    $garage [] = ['id_garage' => $tmp[0]->id_garage, ['id_case' => $key]];
}
```

получается что-то типа такого:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_garage"]=>
    int(2)
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(48)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_garage"]=>
    int(2)
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(49)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_garage"]=>
    int(2)
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(50)
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id_garage"]=>
    int(3)
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(51)
    }
  }
```

Мне нужен массив такого типа:

```
id_garage  => 2 ( id_case => 48, id_case => 49...
id_garage  => 4 ( id_case => 51)
```

Заполняю таким образом:

```
foreach ($garage as $key => $value) {
    $buf [$value['id_garage']][] = ['id_case' => $value[0]['id_case']];
}
```

Получается чуть-чуть не то. Как сформировать такой многомерный массив?

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(17) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(48)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(49)
    }
 [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id_case"]=>
      int(51)
    }
```

Comment: `id_garage  => 2 ( id_case => 48, id_case => 49...`, тут одинаковые ключи `id_case` такого не может быть...

Comment: наверно лучше тогда сделать так: [2] => ('id_case' => [48, 49])

Comment: @Manitikyl как тогда реализовать такую архитектуру? Что бы к id_ garage были привязаны все id_case, которые к нему относятся?

Comment: Попробуй так: `$buf [$value['id_garage']]['id_case'][] = $value[0]['id_case'];`. Если больше никаких данных не будет в массиве, то возможно и нет смысла от `['id_case']` и можно удалить ибо это и так понятно какие там значения.